# Put remainder of division into next line

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have the following data that represents taxes:

```
SELECT trunc(i*i, 3) tax
  FROM generate_series(1.17, 5) i;

    tax   
 -------- 
   1.368  
   4.708  
  10.048  
  17.388  
 (4 rows)
```

Is there any nice way in PostgreSQL to put [mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_(currency)) remainder into next line and if current line is the last it must have all leftovers.

So, I need to make it the following:

```
    tax   
 -------- 
   1.360  
   4.710  
  10.050  
  17.392  
 (4 rows)
```

It could be a query or SQL / PL/pgSQL function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Next row and last row* make sense only when the sort order is defined. I assume that the sort order is defined by `tax asc`.

The first subquery adds row numbers to the data, while the second one calculates the number of rows. The next part is a recursion based on increasing row numbers:

```
with recursive data as (
    select trunc(i*i, 3) tax, row_number() over (order by i) as rn
    from generate_series(1.17, 5) i
),
count as (
    select count(*)
    from data
),
result as (
    select 
        tax, rn, 
        floor(tax* 100)/100 as new_tax, 
        tax- floor(tax* 100)/100 as remainder
    from data
    where rn = 1
union all
    select 
        d.tax, d.rn, 
        case d.rn 
            when count then d.tax+ r.remainder
            else floor((d.tax+ r.remainder)* 100)/100 end as new_tax, 
        d.tax+ r.remainder- floor((d.tax+ r.remainder)* 100)/100 as remainder
    from data d
    join result r on d.rn = r.rn+ 1
    cross join count
) 
select new_tax as tax
from result
order by rn;
```

[Live demo in rextester.](https://rextester.com/SCC77000)